# Error in Perl Script; "Uninitialized Value"?;

Tags: perl

I have the following script:

```
use 5.12.4;
use strict;
use warnings;

say "Enter a functionality:";
while (<>) {
    if (/add/) {
        say "Enter your numbers:";
        my @a = (<>);
        my $sum += $_ for @a;
        say $sum;
    }
}
```

When I run this program, it prompts:

> Enter a functionality:

I enter `add` and it says:

```
Enter your numbers:
```

I enter several numbers on separate lines of input follow by the `[ctrl]Z`  and get the following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $sum in say at C:\myperl\Math-Master\math-master.pl l
ine 11, <> line 9.
```

Why doesn't my code add all of the input? Why does this error come?

Comment: Can you please update the title to make it reflect the actual problem? (Hint: what is the result of `$_ for @a` in the failing case?)

Comment: Would setting `sum` to zero outside the loop fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a postscript loop on a declaration statement. The variable `$sum` is supposed to be incremented each loop, which it cannot be in the same statement it is being declared. You must first declare it, then assign to it with a postscript loop:

```
my $sum;
$sum += $_ for @a;
```

You might consider using [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil) for this, and skipping the temp variable `@a`. And moving the `say` inside the while loop:

```
use List::Util qw(sum);

say "Enter a functionality:";
while (<>) {
    if (/add/) {
        say "Enter your numbers:";
        say "Sum: ", sum(<>);
    }
    say "Enter a functionality:";
}
```

But that is a bit clunky. Why not:

```
while (<>) {
    if (/add/) {
        say "Enter your numbers, separated by space: ";
        say "Sum: ", sum(split " ", <>);
    }
}
```

That way, you do not have to press ctrl-Z (ctrl-D) to stop the input.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to TLPs answer you might consider using something like this:

```
chomp(my @a = (<>));
```

otherwise you would be adding `value1\n'` and `value2\n`. This will of course still work, but you might at some point later wonder where all these strange results are coming from...

I've always missed something like `foldl()` for Perl, but luckily there is [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil). It adds a bit of syntactic sugar...

```
use List::Util qw/sum/;
chomp(my @a = (<>));
my $sum = sum @a;
say $sum;
```

Comment: `foldl` won't win any awards for naming clarity, but from what I can gather, it is a lot like [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it; compare and learn:

```
use 5.012; # implies 'use strict'
use warnings;

say "Enter a functionality:";
while (<>) {
    if (/add/) {
        say "Enter your numbers:";
        my @nums;
        while (1) {
            my $in = <>; # read one line
            last unless $in =~ m/^\d+$/; # only numbers
            push @nums, $in;
        }
        next unless @nums;
        my $sum;
        $sum += $_ for @nums;
        say $sum;
    }
}
```